# Jmeter Proxy giving 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: proxy, jmeter, timeout, gateway, http-status-code-504

I have URL which is like this:

https://110.111.72.72:8001?id=username1

when I use the same URL in browser it works fine and return a result but when I use the same in Jmeter I get a *504 Gateway Timeout error*.

In my organisation we do have the proxy which I have mentioned in the browser LAN -> proxy server settings.
I have tried many things but none worked please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure JMeter to use the same proxy server your browser is using. It can be done in 2 ways:

1. Via command-line arguments. In this case you will need to run JMeter as:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_company_proxy_host -P your_company_proxy_port-u username -a password
   ```
2. Via [Java System Network Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html). In this case you will need to add the following lines to *system.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_company_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_company_proxy_port
   https.proxyHost=your_company_proxy_host
   https.proxyPort=your_company_proxy_port
   ```

More information:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitri T

jmeter -H your_company_proxy_host -P your_company_proxy_port-u username -a password  ---- **Worked Fine**

I didn't try the 2nd option.

Thanks for solving another